# How to make a form which INCLUDES an upload file input

Tags: php, html, database, forms, image-uploading

Hello I'm trying to create a form which includes an upload file input. 
My form is sending data to my database while the file uploaded is stored in the img folder.

Now the form without the upload input works fine. The upload script without the form works fine too. But I can't manage to make them work together. I tried to include the "upload script" in my main form script but it didn't worked. I actually don't khow how this procedure should be done.

What I would like to do is that when I submit the form the data goes in the database and the upload file in my img folder. I think the problem comes somehow from the submit button.

Sorry for posting all my code but I think it's necessary to understand...

This is my addOutfit.php (which sends the data of my form to my database)

```
    require("ajax/db.php"); 

    $message = " "; 

    if ( $_POST ) {

    if (!empty($_POST['type'])){ 

    $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
    $description = htmlspecialchars($_POST['description']);
    $brand = htmlspecialchars($_POST['brand']);
    $material = htmlspecialchars($_POST['material']);
    $type = htmlspecialchars($_POST['type']);
    $color = htmlspecialchars($_POST['color']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO outfit (title, description, brand, material,  type, color) VALUES('$title', '$description', '$brand', '$material', '$type', '$color')";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute(['title' => $title, 'description' => $description, 'brand' => $brand, 'material' => $material, 'type' => $type, 'color' => $color]);

  $message = "The item has been added"; 
   } else {

   $message = "The type field is compulsory"; 
   }
 }
 ?>


 <!--AddOutfit form-->
 <div class="container-fluid" id="addOutfitForm" >

 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
 <form action ="addOutfit.php" method="post" novalidate> 

  <?php if ( $message ) { ?>
  <h3 style="color: red;"><?=$message?></h3>
  <?php } ?>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="type">Type</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="brand">Brand</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="brand">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="color">Color</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="color">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="material">Material</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="material">
    </div>

   <div class="form-group" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Picture</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
   </div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Upload Image">Send</button>     

  </form>
</div>
```

This is my upload.php (my uploading documents script)

```
   <?php
    $target_dir = "img/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);

    if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
   }

   if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
   echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
   $uploadOk = 0;
   }

   if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

 } else {
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
     }
    }
```

Comment: attribute `action` for `<div>` element is not allowed (and it doesn't work). You have to put it in the `<form>` tag (together with `method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"`). The problem now is: what does “addOutfit.php” ?

Comment: Add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in form opening tag

Comment: *"The upload script without the form works fine too."* - so where's that piece of code for it?

Comment: I have two files one called addOutfit.php which sends the data from the form to the database and a file called upload.php to upload files. But I only have ONE form that's the problem... The complete form is currently in the addOutfit.php file

Comment: Don't understand why you duplicated my question it's not the same problem...

Comment: you better get those other guys to delete or modify their answers then. I also asked *""The upload script without the form works fine too." - so where's that piece of code for it?"* earlier but you didn't comment or posted the relevant code. Till then, it remains a duplicate.

Comment: The upload script is the one one I pasted saying   "This is my upload.php(which upload files to my folder)"

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is confusing a bit. You need to check if you have POST request to store the data inside db and check also if you have a file to upload it

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
 // validate and insert the data into db

 // if isset $_FILES["fileToUpload"] update the file
 if(isset($_FILES) && isset($_FILES["fileToUpload"]['name'])) {

 }
}
```

Also don't forget to add the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to the form

```
<form action ="addOutfit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that you just need to add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `<form>` tag.

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp

Submitting files only works when the form data is submitted as multipart.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of

```
<div class="form-group" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <label for="fileToUpload">Picture</label>
```

Have you tried:

```
<form action ="addOutfit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
```